# What's with Windows Firewall warning me about wuapihost and prompting about access?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, windows-firewall

I'm running Win 10 on a little HP Stream 7 tablet and after waking it from a sleep of a whole day got a strange warning from Windows Firewall.

It was telling me 'wuapihost.exe' was trying to access the net and asking if I want to allow it.

Being suspicious I did a Google search. A few people have reported it to MS in recent months but only received a pathetic boilerplate nonanswer with 0 information content: [MS thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/what-is-wuapihostexe/49da7bb1-50fe-4a59-b13d-886f6f02891a).

Should I allow or block this Windows internal component that appears to be part of Windows Update?

Answer (score -1):

Windows 10 far more extensively "phones home" (especially if you enable Cortana) than any previous Windows OS so it's hard to say what's going on. To be safe you can block it and see if Windows Update still runs. If it does you're good to go.

If you break Windows Update, simply remove the block and add it as an exception. If you want better control of the Windows Firewall there are third party utilities that enhance the user interface and allow additional functionality without replacing Windows Firewall itself. An example is [Windows Firewall Control](http://www.binisoft.org/wfc.php).